# Opencv can write flv format?

Tags: opencv, flv

**Try** [**Pastebin code**](http://pastebin.com/HQEvbDCh)....Keep one `test.avi` file in same folder...Please check whether your OpenCv create `new.flv`

I tried this to write `avi` file - **THIS WORKS**

```
    CvVideoWriter *vdowriter = cvCreateVideoWriter(
    "/path/converted.avi",
    CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'),
    20.0,
    cvSize(640,480) );
```

Similarly I tried this to write `flv` file - **THIS DOESNT WORKS**

```
    CvVideoWriter *vdowriter = cvCreateVideoWriter(
    "/path/converted.flv",
    CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', '1'),
    25.0,
    cvSize(640,480) );
```

Comment: Is this Windows? A lot of people report problems trying to do this on Windows. On a side note, you are creating the videos with different framerate, have you tried using framerate 20 with FLV1 ?

Comment: No help....I am taking video stream from Camera....fps 20.0 not working...I tried all possible i could think of...

Comment: You still didn't answered my question and I usually don't ask it twice: is this Windows?

Comment: No its not windows....I am very sorry for that....Please help....It ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Please bro....My mistake I didnt mentioned OS and I know your time is very important to you....Please help me out with this....I am really strucked onto this....HELP

Comment: You can check if OpenCV has been compiled with FFmpeg support, and if your system has all the codecs installed. I assume you are using the latest OpenCV available (v2.3.1).

Comment: @karlphillip I re installed OpenCv 2.3.1.... Still I get this errors....`[flv @ 0x8658e80] Could not find codec parameters (Audio: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, 0 channels)
[flv @ 0x8658e80] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate` `[flv @ 0x86f1c00] Tag FLV1/0x31564c46 incompatible with output codec id '22'`

Comment: @karlphillip I know Opencv2.3.1 supports FLV1 codec but not works for me...Should I install Opencv2.3.1 with some configuration to make it support FLV1...Please help me out with link if you know....I am really in big trouble....Please I need your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try recompiling opencv with ffmpeg.

1. go to the opencv folder
2. type cmake
3. see if it lists ffmpeg as the video encoder/decoder
4. if it does specify ffmpeg download and install it from this site: http://ffmpeg.org/download.html
5. run cmake again in the opencv folder
6. run make and make install in the opencv folder

you can use this tutorial for more assistance: http://www.rainsoft.de/projects/ffmpeg_opencv.html

Comment: Check this out...I have pasted my file here http://pastebin.com/vHqDsB8t (CMakeLists.txt) and http://pastebin.com/zLx6bqH5 (CMakeCache.txt)...Can you please go through it...

Comment: I re installed OpenCv 2.3.1.... Still I get this errors....`[flv @ 0x8658e80] Could not find codec parameters (Audio: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, 0 channels)
[flv @ 0x8658e80] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate` `[flv @ 0x86f1c00] Tag FLV1/0x31564c46 incompatible with output codec id '22'`

Comment: the cmakelists seams fine. did the output for the cmake stated that it uses ffmpeg?

Comment: I have installed Opencv from here `http://ozbots.org/opencv-installation/` and it showed `FFMPEG:YES`

Comment: try converting a video to flv using ffmpeg and see if that works

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses....Its working fine.....`ffmpeg -i avatar.flv -f flv out.flv` was my command....

Comment: not sure what else can you do but if you are really desperate you can save the video as mpeg and then run ffmpeg and convert it. inefficient but it works :/

Comment: It works but my need is different over here....I am doing it live...Can you please tell me can ffmpeg append opencv frames and create `flv` file